# ASP.NET image upload similar to Paperclip or CarrierWave

Tags: asp.net, paperclip, carrierwave

I'm looking to see if anyone knows of any image upload/processing libraries that exist in the asp.net world that are similar to Paperclip or Carrierwave in the ROR space.